# Problemas para instalar webpack para instalar reactjs

Tags: reactjs, xubuntu

quiero instalar reactjs y en el paso de instalar webpack empiezan los problemas.

ejecuto `npm install webpack -g`

y luego me salen estos warnings

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/webpack/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

uso xubuntu 16.04 x64.

¿Que puedo hacer????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Que puedo hacer?

Nada. Cuando instalas módulos siempre hay warnings y esto se debe a los módulos en sí, es decir, dependencias de ellos, quizás deprecated, etc. El warning que muestras se debe a que el módulo [`fsevents`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsevents) solo funciona en MacOS (*"os":"darwin"*) y estás corriendo GNU/Linux. Esto no es problema, porque esta dependencia está marcada como **opcional** en webpack.

Comment: pero luego hago un npm install webpack-dev-server -g y no me instala me da estos errores npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/webpac
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN webpack-dev-server@2.3.0 requires a peer of webpack@^2.2.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN webpack-dev-middleware@1.10.0 requires a peer of webpack@1 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc.0 but none was installed.

Comment: ¿Seguro que no instala? Anda a node_modules y ve si no están allí.

Comment: cuando hago un npm init me dice que tengo creo que modificar el package.json npm init
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible defaults.

See `npm help json` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg> --save` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
name: (react-configuracion) npm WARN init canceled